# What does the dot after the git clone command do?

Tags: git

```
$ git clone git@codebasehq.com:company/projectname/project.git .
```

whats that `.` do if you run command like that ?

Comment: `.` is current directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It checks the project out in the current directory. That is what `.` in general means.

Comment: so if i got to 'cd project' folder and run this command what will happen? is it gona create another new folder named 'project' ?

Comment: @JohnyDerp, No, it would put the contents of the `git` repository into `project`. No new folder will be created.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` after the command is the target location to clone the repo in question to.  This allows you to change it to something else as well.